# Comparing the DateTime Objects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to compare the DateTime value accessed from the Active Record object with the current time.
But not able to find any built in method to do this. 
I tried Using

```
    DateTime.now > @model_name.schedule_time
```

But this is not giving expected result ( may be this does string comparison).

Is there any accurate way to perform comparison with the current time.

Comment: What type does `schedule_time` return? Try to check it with `@model_name.schedule_time.class`

Comment: This could depend on your table-definition, your used database, or maybe how `schedule_time` is defined?

Comment: schedule_time is of type datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question is a bit tricky without knowing the type of `@model_name.schedule_time`.

However in rails `ActiveSupport` provides the methods `#past?` and `#future?` to `Date`, `DateTime` and `Time` instances, so that should take care of your problem:

```
Date.yesterday.past? => true
Time.now.end_of_day.future? => true
DateTime.now.beginning_of_day.past? => true
```

If `@model_name.schedule_time` does not respond to these methods, then it is not one of those types, which explains that the comparison you tried did not work.

Comment: @model_name.schedule_time is of type datetime. I tried @model_name.schedule_time.past? but returns nothing in rails console.

Comment: strange. What is your rails version ? What does `@model_name.schedule_time.inspect` return ?

Comment: @model_name.schedule_time.inspect returns "Wed, 17 Dec 2014 16:05:00 UTC +00:00". i dont know what was happening, now its returning true or false. But behaviour is inverse. even if the time is past it returns false. DateTime.now output is "Wed, 17 Dec 2014 17:38:06 +0530".

Comment: The output definitely confirms that you have a DateTime instance. However your `schedule_time` is expressed in UTC time (Universal Time Coordinated) whereas your local time is expressed in IST (India Standard Time, with an offset of 5:30 hours). The local time you passed, when converted to utc, gives "Wed, 17 Dec 2014 12:08:06 +0000", which is indeed "smaller" than your `schedule_time` (use DateTime.now.utc to see that)

Comment: Thanks for explaination, using @model_name.schedule_time.to_datetime.past? fixed the issue.